# Objects are moved after reopening the file

Tags: modeling, modifiers, archipack-add-on

I'm trying to add windows and doors to the walls of the house I'm making. All objects/walls were made using the Archipack add-on.

I'm using the boolean technique to cut openings in the walls for the doors and windows. It's proven to be a tedious task for me and I carefully spend my time getting everything just where I want it.

I also get a weird glitch after adding the boolean modifier where the windows and doors stretch hilariously large so I have to then go back and re-size them. Perhaps that's a trouble for another post...

**My main problem** here is that after I finally get everything sized and in place and it all looks good, I save and exit. However, when I re-open the file I get this weird problem where random doors and windows are no longer anchored to the walls.

I've repeated the process several times making little tweaks here and there but this problem persists. In the image, I've circled the object that has moved position after saving and closing and I've put a dot of the same color in the location of where it's supposed to be. There's also a random gap in the wall that keeps appearing? I just have no clue and have found no other helpful resources.

I'm using Blender 2.92 and Archipack ver 1.2.84. I've tried downgrading and upgrading without luck.

[image]

Comment: Are shifted objects you adjusted later? It is not definitely boolean issue, seems more like you manipulate with objects in non appropriate way. Addon is using parametric modeling to automate some processes. After reopening some processes where recalculated, the same happens when Boolean operation is pressed.

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks for structuring OP :)

Comment: @vklidu Well I love to see paragraphs everywhere :)

Comment: Thanks for editing my post. I’ll try and keep your standards in mind for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use *Object* or *Edit* mode transformation tools.
For adjusting elements after you release it under *Create tab > Archipack* ... use **Archipack Tab** to manipulate and adjust elements.

[image]

Also check some tutorials ... you don't have to create each wall as separate object.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qJHGig67_0
The best point to start https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki one of the links is Documentation.